# Is it possible to have tyepscript infer generic types from a zod schema passed into a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, zod

I have a pattern to statically type-check endpoint calls in my typescript application, using zod schemas to ensure correctness at runtime. My solution, using generics, works but I have to manually pass types to my function to get the static type-checking to work and I wonder if there is a way, using some more advanced generics magic, to have the correct type to be inferred based on the parameters I supply.

I define objects I call routes which contain all the information required (http method, url) to perform a call to an endpoint and zods schemas defining

Here's an example of a route (Note, I'm using a naming convention where types use capitals and a types schema would have the same name with a preceeding $)

```
const $UpdateStaffMemberCallParams = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number.int().positive(),
});

const $UpdateStaffMemberUrlParams = z.object({
  staffMemberId: z.number().int().positive(),
});

const updateStaffMemberRoute = {
  getUrl(params: {staffMemberId: number}): string {
    return `staff_members/${staffMemberId}`
  },
  method: 'POST',
  $CallParams: $UpdateStaffMemberCallParams,
  $UrlParams: $UpdateStaffMemberUrlParams,
}
```

I then define an apply route function which would call the endpoint and return the result as a promise

```
type CallParams = object;
type PathParams = object;
type GetPathFunc<TPath extends PathParams> = (params: TPath) => string;
type RouteMethod = typeof Methods.GET_METHOD | typeof Methods.POST_METHOD | typeof Methods.DELETE_METHOD | typeof Methods.PATCH_METHOD | typeof Methods.PUT_METHOD;
type Route<TPath extends PathParams, TCall extends CallParams> = {
  getPath: GetPathFunc<TPath>,
  method: RouteMethod,
  $CallParams: z.ZodType<TCall>;
  $PathParams: z.ZodType<TPath>;
};

function throwBadMethod(method: RouteMethod) {
  throw new Error(`unsuppored value supplied for route method: ${method}`);
}

type ApplyRouteParams <TPath extends PathParams, TCall extends CallParams> = {
  httpRequest: AxiosInstance,
  callParams: TCall,
  pathParams: TPath,
  route: Route<TPath, TCall>,
};

export function applyRoute<TPath extends PathParams, TCall extends CallParams>(params: ApplyRouteParams<TPath, TCall>): Promise<AxiosResponse<TCall>> {
  const {
    route,
    httpRequest,
  } = params;
  const pathParams = route.$PathParams.parse(params.pathParams);
  const callParams = route.$CallParams.parse(params.callParams);

  switch (route.method) {
    case Methods.GET_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.get<TCall>(
        route.getPath.apply(null, [pathParams]),
        callParams,
      );
    case Methods.POST_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.post<TCall>(
        route.getPath(pathParams),
        callParams,
      );
    case Methods.PATCH_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.patch<TCall>(
        route.getPath(pathParams),
        callParams,
      );
    case Methods.DELETE_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.delete<TCall>(
        route.getPath(pathParams),
        callParams,
      );
    case Methods.PUT_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.put<TCall>(
        route.getPath(pathParams),
        callParams,
      );
    default:
      throwBadMethod(route.method);
  }
}
```

Once I have a AxiosInstance setup somewhere called httpRequest and I can call appRoute like this and typescript will statically make sure everything is correct.

```
applyRoute<z.infer<typeof updateStaffMemberRoute.$PathParams>, z.infer<typeof updateStaffMemberRoute.$CallParams.>>({
  httpRequest,
  callParams: {
    name: 'John',
    age: 22,
  },
  pathParams: {
    staffMemberId: staffMember.id,
  },
  route: updateStaffMemberRoute,
})
```

Having to pass in the generic types manually like this creates the possibility of the type somehow not updating in sync with the route so I'm Inferring it from the schemas inside the route to makes this a bit less likely but I still have to write them every time and so could get them the wrong way round and the z.infer() stuff is kind of noisy. I can make this look a bit better by creating nicely named types from the schemas, in the file that defines them, but this way you know for sure that the types used are related to the schemas I passed in.

The point of this question is that I'm curious if there is a way to setup the type definitions on applyRoute() that will get typescript to infer TPath and TCall from the schemas so that the call becomes this?

```
applyRoute({
  httpRequest,
  callParams: {
    name: 'John',
    age: 22,
  },
  pathParams: {
    staffMemberId: staffMember.id,
  },
  route: updateStaffMemberRoute,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this (with a bit of help) and the key was that `ZodType<T>` (the type that represents zod schemas) has an `_input` property which describe the type that is expected to be supplied to the schema for parsing. By mapping into the `_input` property for the schemas types passed into my Route type its possible to extract the type required.

Here is how my example would look with this solution

```
type CallParams = object;
type PathParams = object;
type GetPathFunc<TPath extends PathParams> = (params: TPath) => string;
type RouteMethod = typeof Methods.GET_METHOD | typeof Methods.POST_METHOD | typeof Methods.DELETE_METHOD | typeof Methods.PATCH_METHOD | typeof Methods.PUT_METHOD;
type Route<TPath extends PathParams, TCall extends CallParams> = {
  getPath: GetPathFunc<TPath>,
  method: RouteMethod,
  $CallParams: z.ZodType<TCall>;
  $PathParams: z.ZodType<TPath>;
};

function throwBadMethod(method: RouteMethod) {
  throw new Error(`unsuppored value supplied for route method: ${method}`);
}

type InferRouteTypes<T extends Route<any, any>> = {
  pathParams: T["$PathParams"]["_input"],
  callParams: T["$CallParams"]["_input"],
};

type ApplyRouteParams <T extends Route<any, any>> = {
  httpRequest: AxiosInstance,
  route: Route<T>,
} & InferRouteTypes<T>;

export function applyRoute<T extends Route<any, any>>(params: ApplyRouteParams<T>): Promise<AxiosResponse<T["$CallParams"]["_input"]>> {
  const {
    route,
    httpRequest,
  } = params;
  const pathParams = route.$PathParams.parse(params.pathParams);
  const callParams = route.$CallParams.parse(params.callParams);

  switch (route.method) {
    case Methods.GET_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.get(
        route.getPath.apply(null, [pathParams]),
        callParams,
      );
    case Methods.POST_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.post(
        route.getPath(pathParams),
        callParams,
      );
    case Methods.PATCH_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.patch(
        route.getPath(pathParams),
        callParams,
      );
    case Methods.DELETE_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.delete(
        route.getPath(pathParams),
        callParams,
      );
    case Methods.PUT_METHOD:
      return httpRequest.put(
        route.getPath(pathParams),
        callParams,
      );
    default:
      throwBadMethod(route.method);
  }
}
```

With this the call can be done without explicitly passing generics, keeping the in sync with the schema supplied in the route object and calls using the follow sytax is properly statically checked by typescript

```
applyRoute({
  httpRequest,
  callParams: {
    name: 'John',
    age: 22,
  },
  pathParams: {
    staffMemberId: staffMember.id,
  },
  route: updateStaffMemberRoute,
})
```